# How to get all possible values for an existing ENUM or SET - field

Tags: symfony, enums, doctrine, set

I'm using Doctrine in Symfony4.
How do I retrieve all possible values for an ENUM or SET column on this base?

Comment: Add some PHP code if you want anyone to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem of gettin enum value , just change the database from enum to int

Comment: This clearly doesn't help with the problem itself. You're just proposing a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you add an abstraction layer instead of extending directly Enum, even if is not necessary:

```
class AppEnum extends Enum
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $value;
```

Then you just need to add static function on it:

```
public static function choices()
{
    $values = [];

    foreach (static::toArray() as  $value) {
        $values[] = new static($value);
    }

    return $values;
}
```

Example; assume you have an enum:

```
class ExampleEnum extends AppEnum
{
    public const A = '1';
    public const B = '2';
    public const C = '3';
```

And then:

```
dump(ExampleEnum::choices());
```

will return :

```
    array:3 [
  0 => App\Domain\ExampleEnum {#15121
    #value: "1"
    -key: "A"
  }
  1 => App\Domain\ExampleEnum {#15065
    #value: "2"
    -key: "B"
  }
  2 => App\Domain\ExampleEnum {#15124
    #value: "3"
    -key: "C"
  }
]
```